# how to redirect all server requests to index.html file in node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, request

I have found the solution to error from [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20for%20the%20dreaded,is%20supposed%20to%20do%20it)

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

but I am not able to understand what I have actually write in that index.html file

[image]

Comment: index.html should contains the all the html code which necessary to render your app. For example: https://github.com/moshfeu/synced-shopping-list/blob/master/public/index.html (This app created by create-react-app, but it applies to regular react app too)

Comment: where I have to write this code in backend or frontend

Comment: first i am creating build of react app and than i am using that build static in my backend

Comment: In the frontend. `i am using that build static in my backend` how are you using it? If you put the html file also in build, so your code should be `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html')`

Comment: no i am using build file static in my backend

Comment: You mention you're using React. How you bundle (npm run build) the react scripts?

Comment: i have added screen snipt of my backend files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223274/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-arya).

Comment: Further our chat, just to recap (for future readers), OP is using `react-scripts` so the index.html is under `build` folder therefor, the server serves this html file using `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem all thanks to @Mosh Feu Who helped me a lot in this problem solving
you can see discussion in this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223274/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-arya)

***NOTE*** : use index.html file after declaring routes to api

```
app.use("/api", indexRouter);

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/build/index.html'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```